# SQL request get data last year over 30 days

Tags: mysql, sql

I lean on a request and I block to add the constraint on 30 days. I get back the sales of the orders of last year but I would like to add on a period of 30 days.

Here is my request:

```
SELECT SUM(total_paid)/COUNT(id_order)
        FROM ps_orders o
        WHERE o.date_add BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(
        CASE
            WHEN YEAR( DATE_SUB( now(), INTERVAL 364 DAY ) ) = YEAR(now() )
            THEN DATE_SUB(concat(YEAR(now()),'-',MONTH(now()),'-01'), INTERVAL 371 DAY)
            ELSE DATE_SUB(concat(YEAR(now()),'-',MONTH(now()),'-01'), INTERVAL 364 DAY) END, '%Y/%m/%d') AND
        CASE
            WHEN YEAR( DATE_SUB( now(), INTERVAL 364 DAY ) ) = YEAR(now() )
            THEN DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 371 DAY)
            ELSE DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 364 DAY) END
        AND valid=1
```

30 days

```
SELECT SUM(total_paid)/COUNT(id_order)
        FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'orders o
        WHERE o.date_add BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), "%Y/%m/%d") AND NOW()
        AND o.valid=1
```

That must return me the turnover as per `total_paid` and `id_order`.

[image: turnover]

Thank you for help.

Comment: It would become easier if you show data in the table and your desired result. Thanks

Comment: The question has not translated well sample data and expected output would help.

Comment: I must have as a result the total turnover example: 385,45 € thanks

Comment: In that case just write select 385.45. But seriously I cannot understand what you mean by '. I get back the sales of the orders of last year but I would like to add on a period of 30 days' - does that mean for the 395 days prior to today?

Comment: I want to recover the turnover of the previous year over a period of 30 days. We are the 05/08/19, I want to recover the turnover of 05/08/18 by adding INTERVAL 1 MONTH

Comment: I made the requests for the 30 days on the current year (see code) and I would like to add on the last year

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I _think_ you mean a subselect off 'YYYY-MM' and total_paid. Then you do the SUM on this subselect grouping by the year-month values.

Comment: Is the logic for your first query correct? you only fetch 2018-08-02 to 2018-08-06. Are you simply saying for this query that you want to get 2018-08 to todays day ie 2018-08-01 to 2018-08-05?

Comment: I want to retrieve the figure on 30 days: today - 1 year -> 05/08/18, 04/08/18, 03/08/18, 02/08 / 18,01 / 08 / 18,31 / 07 / 18, ..... 30 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be looking for a rolling 30 days from last year based on todays date. You could do this with date_sub using this function twice to get the lower boundary. For example I have a table called dates which contains all dates from 2000.

```
SELECT DTE, date_sub(date_sub(date(now()), interval 1 year), interval 30 day) lastyrplus30,
                date_sub(date(now()), interval 1 year) lastyr
from dates
where dte between date_sub(date_sub(date(now()), interval 1 year), interval 30 day) and
                        date_sub(date(now()), interval 1 year)
;
```

which yields

```
+------------+--------------+------------+
| DTE        | lastyrplus30 | lastyr     |
+------------+--------------+------------+
| 2018-07-06 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-07-07 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-07-08 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-07-09 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-07-10 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-07-11 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-07-12 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-07-13 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-07-14 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-07-15 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-07-16 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-07-17 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-07-18 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-07-19 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-07-20 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-07-21 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-07-22 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-07-23 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-07-24 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-07-25 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-07-26 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-07-27 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-07-28 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-07-29 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-07-30 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-07-31 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-08-01 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-08-02 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-08-03 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-08-04 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
| 2018-08-05 | 2018-07-06   | 2018-08-05 |
+------------+--------------+------------+
31 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

If you want to test this further and you have something like dates or a calender table you could substitute now() with a user defined variable. for example

```
set @now = '2019-05-20';

SELECT DTE, date_sub(date_sub(date(@now), interval 1 year), interval 30 day) lastyrplus30,
                date_sub(date(@now), interval 1 year) lastyr
from dates
where dte between date_sub(date_sub(date(@now), interval 1 year), interval 30 day) and
                        date_sub(date(@now), interval 1 year) ;
```

Results in

```
+------------+--------------+------------+
| DTE        | lastyrplus30 | lastyr     |
+------------+--------------+------------+
| 2018-04-20 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-04-21 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-04-22 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-04-23 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-04-24 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-04-25 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-04-26 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-04-27 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-04-28 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-04-29 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-04-30 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-05-01 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-05-02 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-05-03 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-05-04 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-05-05 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-05-06 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-05-07 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-05-08 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-05-09 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-05-10 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-05-11 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-05-12 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-05-13 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-05-14 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-05-15 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-05-16 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-05-17 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-05-18 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-05-19 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
| 2018-05-20 | 2018-04-20   | 2018-05-20 |
+------------+--------------+------------+
31 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```